# Initializing controller failed (RRBOT tutorial)

Tags: ros, gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi folks.

I'm working on the tutorial of Gazebo 1.9 with rrbot and currently facing the following error messages.

From the controller start launch file:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1375388998.774908] [0.000000] Loading controller: joint1_position_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1375389000.170747] [28.387000] Failed to load joint1_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1375389000.171134] [28.387000] Loading controller: joint2_position_controller
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1375389001.195123] [29.373000] Failed to load joint2_position_controller
```

And from the Gazebo launch file:

```
[ERROR] [1375388999.165926429, 27.406000000]: Exception thrown while initializing controller joint1_position_controller.
Could not find resource 'joint1' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
[ERROR] [1375388999.166263170, 27.406000000]: Initializing controller 'joint1_position_controller' failed
[ERROR] [1375389000.189563304, 28.401000000]: Exception thrown while initializing controller joint2_position_controller.
Could not find resource 'joint2' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
[ERROR] [1375389000.190056911, 28.404000000]: Initializing controller 'joint2_position_controller' failed
```

I have followed the tutorial step by step and used the gazebo_ros_demos package.

Thank for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4040/initializing-controller-failed-(rrbot-tutorial)/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Well, I changed a lot of things, so I'm not sure of what was the root cause.

What I did:

- install ros-hydro-desktop-full
- install gazebo, which has removed the previous package, but only the meta package (fixed in the meantime)
- install ros_control from the source (did not manage to make the deb version work)
- install ros_controller, control_toolbox and real_time (since again the package were missing or inconsistent in the debs)

And this is now working fine.

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-08-06**:
I think the debians were just out of date, I just released a update that should be in public with the next Hydro public sync